# I can't reach a particular local web app that is running on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a web app that used to run on IIS at http://localhost:3878/Admin; however now for some reason I get this error when I try to access it in a browser:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> The connection was reset.
>
> Try:
>
> Checking the connection
>
> Checking the proxy and the firewall
>
> Running Windows Network Diagnostics
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Why would I be getting this error all of a sudden when the app worked earlier today? I checked in IIS to make sure the app is started. The IIS logs are not showing any requests to this app. Event Viewer shows a compile error related to this app (I tried to access an include aspx page directly from the browser; I want to fix that issue with the web app where it's displaying the source code from the aspx pages that are used in #include statements) but that shouldn't take the app down once and for all should it?

Comment: What does `netstat -aon` say? Anything at port 3878?

Comment: Can you see it in IIS? What happens if you right cilck / browse a file in IIS?

Comment: Could you get it fixed by setting your website to https instead of http? Secondly, could you see that error in C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR? If so, it is recommended to monitor the connection via network monitor. In addition, did you install any update today earlier?

Comment: @LexLi There are two lines that contain port 3878:

TCP    0.0.0.0:3878           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4

and

TCP    [::]:3878              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The site does exist in IIS; if I right click it and hit "explore" I see the folder containing the site.

Comment: @JokiesDing The site is already configured to use HTTPS. Looks like I needed to access it using an https url rather than an http url. Thanks!

Comment: Not “explore”. Use “browse”. Then it will tell the actual URL you should be using.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else face ERR_CONNECTION_RESET with http. Then you could try https first. If https binding fix the problem. It would help narrow down the root cause.
You may need to check whether require https has been enabled or mistake. In some case, enable https or HSTS in project will cause ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

Of course, enable https would be considered as a workaround.